# How do I grab a value from an input in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

how do i grab a value from an input element in javascript? For some reason my code is not executing. This is my HTML code:

```
   <section id ="my-life" style="margin-left:39em;">

   <input class="jenny" placeholder="Your First Name"/> <br /><br />

   <button id="get">Subscribe</button>

   <br /><br />

  <div id ="whitelion">Thank You!</div>



    This is my javascript code:

   function buttonClicked() {
   var Niche = document.getElementsByClassName("jenny");
   var results = document.getElementById("whitelion");


   results.innerHTML = "Hello" + Niche[0].value;
```

}

Comment: Your code is not written inside the `<script>` tag that is why it will not work

Comment: It's not in a script tag, and also you never actually call your function

Comment: use `value` to get the value of an input: `document.getElementsByClassName("jenny").value`

Comment: it will be better if you will post same as u tried in your coding its very difficult to understand through your question

Comment: Two things: one, change your button to say <button id="get" onclick="buttonClicked()">Subscribe</button>. Two, add a space after "Hello" in your results.innerHTML so it says "Hello "

Comment: @Michel document.getElementsByClassName returns a collection, not a single object, so your suggestion doesn't work. OP is already calling it correctly later in the code using Niche[0].value . https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Answer (score 2):

```js
function buttonClicked() {
  var Niche = document.getElementsByClassName("jenny");
  var results = document.getElementById("whitelion");
  results.innerHTML = "Hello " + Niche[0].value;
}
```

```html
<input class="jenny" placeholder="Your First Name"/>
<br /><br />
<button onclick='buttonClicked();'>Subscribe</button>
<br /><br />
<div id ="whitelion">Thank You!</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <section id ="my-life" style="margin-left:39em;">

   <input class="jenny" placeholder="Your First Name"/> <br /><br />

   <button id="get">Subscribe</button>

   <br /><br />

  <div id ="whitelion">Thank You!</div>



<script>
   function buttonClicked() {
     var Niche = document.getElementsByClassName("jenny");
     var results = document.getElementById("whitelion");

     results.innerHTML = "Hello" + Niche[0].value;
   }

  document.getElementById('get').onclick = buttonClicked;

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code on the editor. It works fine. But you must include your JS code inside a `<script>` element. And put it in the bottom of the document.

```js
function buttonClicked() {
   var Niche = document.getElementsByClassName("jenny");
   var results = document.getElementById("whitelion");


   results.innerHTML = "Hello " + Niche[0].value;
}
```

```html
<section id ="my-life">

   <input class="jenny" placeholder="Your First Name"/> <br /><br />

   <button id="get" onclick="buttonClicked()">Subscribe</button>

   <br /><br />

  <div id ="whitelion">Thank You!</div>
  <br/>
  </section>
```